# deletion algorithm in array data structure

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I can't understand deletion algorithm.

Variables:

LA: Liner Array

N: Number of elements in LA

K: Position at which deletion should be done

Algorithm:

```
2. Set J = K 
3. Repeat steps 4 and 5 while J < N-1
4.          Set LA[J] = LA[J + 1]
5.          Set J = J+1
6. Set N = N-1
7. Stop
```

In this algorithm step 4, element at index "J" becomes the same as element at index "J+1". But there is no step of removing the element at index "J+1" then how does it get deleted.

like if array is 2,4,6,8 and we have to delete element at index 3 then loop will not execute and just N (no of element in array) get reduced. How the element get deleted?

if we have to remove element at index 2 then first 6 becomes 8 but still 4th element remains. 2,4,8,8 that will be the array. How the element get deleted?

Answer (score 0):

Let the array be `[2,3,6,7,8]` and index for deletion be 3. The array after each iteration is:

1. `[2,3,7,7,8]    # element at index 3 got replaced with element at index 4`
2. `[2,3,7,8,8]    # element at index 4 got replaced with element at index 5`
3. `N-=1`, so now N = 5-1 = 4.

For future computations, length of list will be used as `N`, which is equal to 4. So the 5th element wouldn't be considered, effectively rendering it useless. However, at any point, if you use something like `N = array.length()`, the last element will also be considered and then the program would give incorrect results.

Answer (score 0):

visualize it this way

let's say K=2 (you want to delete the element at 2nd position)

LA = [3,1,5,9,6]

N = 5

now according to the algo what happening is you are shifting all the elements which are to the right of 2nd element to one place left

this is what happens inside the while loop

```
1st iteration :

//LA = [3,1,5,9,6] (before 1st iteration)
J = 2
LA[J] = LA[J+1] (shifting of elements to left)

//LA = [3,5,5,9,6] (after 1st iteration)

2nd iteration :

//LA = [3,5,5,9,6] (before 2nd iteration)
J = 3
LA[J] = LA[J+1] (shifting of elements to left)

//LA = [3,5,9,9,6] (after 2nd iteration)

3rd iteration :

//LA = [3,5,9,9,6] (before 3rd iteration)
J = 4
LA[J] = LA[J+1] (shifting of elements to left)

//LA = [3,5,9,6,6] (after 3rd iteration)
```

after 3rd iteration j = 5 and 5 == N-1 so comes out of the loop

now when N = N-1 means that we are removing the last element (5th element in this case)